# Micro Frontend architecture and different teams

Tags: architecture, ui, microfrontends

I often get the argument that, if only a single team is working on the UI development, then the UI should not be developed as a set of Micro Frontends, with each one representing a subdomain.

I would agree with the higher maintenance argument of such an architecture, but if one considered each Micro Frontend as an element(component) of a modular Software System, designed for different products, with each product running a specific subset(or full set) of those Micro Frontend elements, maybe it makes more sense and has nothing to do with the number of teams developing the UI after all.

Question is:

Is the number of teams developing the UI the sole factor to base the decision for a monolithic or Micro Frontend base UI?

It does not seem to be the case for me, but I see a lot of half-baked articles on the internet claim so, and a lot of developers blindly believing so.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Architectural decisions are rarely, if ever, based on a sole factor.**

The higher maintenance imposed on a single team is a significant factor to consider. However, it's possible that anticipated growth, size and experience of the team, and/or size of the feature might be compelling counter-arguments in favor of that choice.